# Find value in row and update other row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with a dataset that has a time column. I want to find if a certain time exists or not expired `'14:26:00'` and update the `values` row with a label let's say a 1 if this time exists or not. Now there are about 3500 samples of data generated over the course of 30 seconds so an efficient way with minimal code would be desirable.

Here is what I have tried, slightly different versions of the code and some others that have not worked.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df.loc[df['time'].str.contains('14:26:00'), 'value' = "1"]



Data Sample [ file.csv ]
  cOne, cTwo, cThree, cFour, cFive, cSix, cSeven, time
0, 5.73, 33.17, 6.49, 8.09, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.798
1, 8.75, 223.76, 3.77, 11.83, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.799
2, 2.09, 73.88, -3.89, 10.23, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.800
3, 3.38, -114.34, 7.84, 12.79, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.827
4, 1.46, -97.70, 9.72, 7.68, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.828
5, 5.22, -39.64, 9.90, 11.69, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.829
6, 4.85, -72.94, -0.88, 7.55, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.830
7, 2.82, 16.36, -9.63, 8.98, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.857
8, 1.15, 77.99, 10.60, 10.34, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.857
9, 5.24, 35.94, 3.32, 8.07, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.859
10, -2.77, 49.23, 6.48, 4.68, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 09:48:32.859
```

Comment: That's not valid python code, and it's impossible to say anything without seeing a sample of the input file.

Comment: it's valid if you assume that I imported pandas in this case. My question is how to actually accomplish what I mentioned above; i'm not going to pollute the post with everything I have tried for the past 45 mins as it would be very distracting. I will update my question with a data sample though if it makes it easier for others.

Comment: I was referring to the syntax error you get from unclosed brackets

Answer (score 0):

in extention to your code give astype int, boolean values can convert to int

```
         date
0   2016-02-08 12:26:00
1   2016-02-08 12:56:00
2   2016-02-08 13:26:00
3   2016-02-08 13:56:00
4   2016-02-08 14:26:00
5   2016-02-08 14:56:00

df.date.astype(str).str.contains('14:26:00').astype(int)
```

Out:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     0
```

"if" condition to assign different value

```
df.date.apply(lambda x:'value' if '14:26:00' in str(x) else 'some')

0      some
1      some
2      some
3      some
4     value
5      some
```

Comment: I see printing that out does what I want but in this case do you know how I can apply this to an if condition and then create a new dataframe based on if that row is true or not?

Comment: If I try to compare in a if conditon to a boolean I get "value error: the truth value of seriess is abigious"

Comment: yes @travishaycock, just use lambda function and by iterating with the value and give your specific ans,